# How to Hide Product Price in magento admin panel

Tags: magento

I want to hide the price value in price tab in the admin panel of magento. I've searched on Google and the suggestions I found doesn't work. Can I, please, get proper guidelines to hide the price?

Thanks
Tarun Sukhadiya

Answer (score 0):

Run this query in database :

Update `your db name`.`eav_attribute` SET `is_user_defined` = '1' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code` = 'price';
Then go to catalog attribute sets and select your set then unassigned the price attribute.